# Pushing files to my tablet from PC

Tags: file-transfer

I have a Sony Tablet S.

When I'm browsing the [Google Play](https://play.google.com) webpage on my PC, I can install applications by just pushing the **Install** button and choosing my device - all done on my PC. Then a moment later, automagically, the application is installing on my tablet.

Is there some similar functionality to send pdf/mp3/mp4 files to my tablet from my PC?

Comment: Apart from mails with attachments, I only know about some solutions involving a server software app on the device :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Awesome Drop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dashwire.drop) does exactly what you are looking for.

Drag and drop into a page on your pc's browser and the are automatically downloaded to your device.

Edit:

Here are a couple other options:

1. **[Wifi Syncr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appricoo.android.tools.wifisyncr):** If you are connected to the same wifi network this will do exactly what you want.  You basically setup a shared folder in Windows and anything you put in that folder is pushed to the designated folder on your device.  It's a one way sync: PC => Device.  You *may* be able to set this up to work remotely over the internet if you use a [Dynamic DNS service](http://dyn.com/dns/) but I don't really know.
2. You can use a cloud service like Flow mentioned in his answer and couple that with an app that will automatically keep the local folders on your device synced so you won't have to manually download each file.  I personally use **[DropSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.dropsync) with my Dropbox account**. I've also used **[FolderSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full) with Google Drive** (FolderSync actually syncs with tons of cloud services).  Both are paid apps but have lite versions that limit you to one folder which would work.  The drawback to this method is that there is a way to set it up to detect changes on your local device and sync immediately, however it can't detect changes to the cloud directory so files would only be downloaded to your device on the sync schedule you setup.

Comment: This one is the closest to what I want. The best would be something like this but using my google account and Google Drive so that I would be able to drop the file at work and later when someone turns my tablet on at home it will be automatically downloaded.

Comment: @SeeR I updated my answer with a couple other options that might be closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I think most similar way to do this like what Google Play does, is:

If your files are saved on PC, and your device is connected to the same network as your PC (including local networks without internet connection), then you can use remote android controllers, like free and powerful [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) to upload files from PC to the device *(batch files and folder transfers are supported)*.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of explicitly pushing a file to your Android device, have a look at cloud storage providers. For example [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/) or [Google Drive.](https://drive.google.com/#my-drive) IMHO that is a superior approach, but it comes with two drawbacks:

1. privacy/security concerns
2. (Sometimes) the file will have to be uploaded first before you can retrieve it on your device. There is no direct file transfer from your PC to the device which is desirable when dealing with large files.